# Emulator does not start

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using android studio 2.3. After I updated my android sdk to the latest version, I noticed that my emulator stopped working. When I try to start the emulator it says "Waiting for target device to come online". But it goes nowhere and the emulator never shows up. After reading some posts, I installed some extra libraries Intel and ARM apis for each version of Android like 5.0, 6.0 but still that did not work. Restarted my machine, IDE, invalidated caches but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your emulator. I had a similar issue when I updated to an earlier version (2.2.2), and removing and rebuilding my emulators did the trick after installing the appropriate apis and packages. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately, I tried this option and it didn't seem to work. However, I was able to get rid of the issue. I had to update the android home in my bash profile to match the path of the android sdk mentioned in my android studio. That solved my issue.